# How do I find the absolute path of the currently running Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script which wants to determine its absolute path in order to find some data files that are stored relative to the script.

What's the simplest/best way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done simply using:

```
File.expand_path $0
```